# I asking about pcap library (See nothing about data.)

Tags: c, linux, wireshark, pcap

I installed libpcap library (libpcap-dev) and making a pcap test code about find default interface devices.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pcap.h>

int main(){

    char *dev=0;

    char ebuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE]="";

    dev = pcap_lookupdev(ebuf);

    if(dev == 0){

        fprintf(stderr, "error find device: %s\n",ebuf);

        return 1;

    }

    printf("Device: %s\n",dev);

    return 0;

}
```

After typing my code, I compiled it with a gcc.

```
$gcc –o test test.c –lpcap
```

I expected the result

```
$gcc –o test test.c –lpcap    
Device: XXXXX
```

but after compiled it, Nothing to see about data like a picture.

```
$gcc –o test test.c –lpcap
$
```

[Result.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geb33.png)

So, I also found another example about pcap, but same result.

I want to know what the problem is.

My development environment is Ubuntu 18.04 and IDE is Eclipse.

Comment: Please do not use a picture to show text.

Comment: I can't upload picture because I less than ten reputation

Comment: Your first problem appears to be that you're not running your program after compiling it.

Comment: You don't get it? Do not post a *picture* when you can copy the *text*.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all C compilers generate code but don't *run* the code after they've generated it.

You have to run the compiled program in a separate command.

Just try typing the command `./test` after you've run gcc.